# Host name resolution failed for 'Microsoft.Network'

Tags: vnet

Not allowed to do any operation on Vnet, like Vnet Integration etc , faling on North Europe also.

Failed to save subnet 'apps'. Error: 'Host name resolution failed for 'Microsoft.Network'; cannot fulfill the request.'

Answer (score 0):

I see the same issue. 
It might be related to Azure current failure with ARM

> Starting at 08:45 UTC on 04 Jun 2020, a subset of customers may
>   experience issues with resource creation for services that depend on
>   the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) platform.
>
> Engineers have identified a fix and have started to deploy to affected
>   regions. Customers may continue to experience latency or failures
>   while creating resources for some services. The next update will be
>   provided in 60 minutes, or as events warrant.
>
> This message was last updated at 14:33 UTC on 04 June 2020

You can check the updated Azure services status here - https://status.azure.com/en-us/status

**EDIT:** Azure team announced that the issue is resolved now